# deploying javafx 1.3 application with swing.filechooser

Tags: javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a Java application and I integrated **JavaFX 1.3** on it. I have spent more than three days trying to deploy it as a Web Start Application and it is impossible.

I have a jar running with the console (`javafx -jar MatchTestCaseGenerator-2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`) but when I try to execute the jnlp I have the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:667)
at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolderManager.get(ShellFolderManager.java:57)
at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(ShellFolder.java:227)
at javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getDefaultDirectory(FileSystemView.java:404)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(JFileChooser.java:552)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:334)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:286) ...
```

I have the jar file signed and verified and my JNLP file is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:/Users/ana/Projects/Java/workspace/Match Test Case Generator 2.0/target" href="MatchTestCaseGenerator.jnlp">
 <information>
    <title>Match Test Case Generator</title>
    <vendor>KV </vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>some_description</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut>
        <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
      <extension name="JavaFX Runtime" href="http://dl.javafx.com/1.3/javafx-rt.jnlp"/>
    <jar href="MatchTestCaseGenerator-2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.sun.javafx.runtime.main.Main" progress-class="com.javafx.progressbar.ProgressManager">
     <argument>MainJavaFXScript=com.knowledgevalues.mtcg.javafx.MainFx</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Am I missing something? should I introduces a policy file in the jar?? I'm totally lost

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add next section to your jnlp file:

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I worked. But now, I have this other problem:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/runtime/eula/Eula
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)...

Any idea?

Comment: it looks like you don't have JavaFX 1.3 runtime installed. Does any JavaFX 1.3 application works through jnlp on your machine?

Comment: Yes! I have other javaFX 1.3 applications from Oracle that works well and if I try to run my jar with "javafx -jar MatchTestCaseGenerator-2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" it is working well. 

Another thing that I've checked is to not have duplicates files in my jar (specially the class Eula.class) and I have only this class in the specified path (com/sun/javafx/runtime/eula/Eula).

So... I don't know what is happening or what can i do next...

Comment: unfortunately javafx 1.3 is a bit obsolete, so I can't give you exact advise now. You can try to take working FX1.3 app with jnlp and substitute it's jar with your one (and update jnlp accordingly).

Comment: Yes, I already tried but i think that i should have something wrong in my jar because this solution is not working either. Thanks anyway. If I can find the final solution, I will post it.

Comment: Well, finally, I got it. It was a problem of the jar file. It had some  javafx classes and it shouldn't. I remove all of them except the Main.class and it worked!!

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Congratulations, you may want to update your question or add this info as another answer to help someone with similiar problem

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to remove all the folders that included javafx classes except the Main class.

With that, it worked without problems!!